# How to get list of class variables in the order they are defined?

Tags: python, list, class, variables

I have a class that specifies the column layout of a csv file as:

```
class RecordLayout(object):
    YEAR = 0
    DATE = 1
    MONTH = 2
    ID = 3
    AGE = 4
    SALARY = 5
```

I need to get the list of the class variables in the order they are defined.

So far, I tried:

```
[attr for attr in dir(RecordLayout()) if not callable(attr) and not attr.startswith("__")]
```

but it returns:

```
['AGE', 'DATE', 'ID', 'MONTH', 'SALARY', 'YEAR']
```

which is the class variables ordered alphabetically. I need the variables to be returned in the order they are defined in the class:

```
['YEAR', 'DATE', 'MONTH', 'ID', 'AGE', 'SALARY']
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: *"I need the variables to be returned in the order they are defined"* - for what purpose?

Comment: The order in which they are defined isn't remembered, you need to do it some other way.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: to get the header of the csv files in a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an [Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) for this.

```
>>> class RecordLayout(Enum):
...     YEAR = 0
...     DATE = 1
...     MONTH = 2
...     ID = 3
...     AGE = 4
...     SALARY = 5
...
>>> for i in RecordLayout:
...   print(i)
...
RecordLayout.YEAR
RecordLayout.DATE
RecordLayout.MONTH
RecordLayout.ID
RecordLayout.AGE
RecordLayout.SALARY
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. I can do something like this [name for name, member in RecordLayout.__members__.items()], which returns ['YEAR', 'DATE', 'MONTH', 'ID', 'AGE', 'SALARY'].

Answer (score 0):

Old question but top google search result, so here's my answer after some more research.

Use `RecordLayout().__dir__()` and filter out the entries which are not needed. `__dir__()` should provide the entries in the order they were defined, whereas `dir()` applies a sort.

How did I get here?

Starting with "[PEP 520 -- Preserving Class Attribute Definition Order](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0520/)" and then ended up at this discussion thread  https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2016-September/146382.html

```
  >>> class Example:
  ...     def __dir__(self):
  ...         return "first second third fourth".split()
  ...
  >>> dir(Example())
  ['first', 'fourth', 'second', 'third']
  >>> Example().__dir__()
  ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']
```